# Json and foreach + limit to 4 results in loop

Tags: php, json, filter, foreach, categories

I have an api with json and i want to make a table with 4 columns in one line and filter by categories.
My code is:

```
echo '<table>';
foreach($jsonData['pricing'] as $keyDec => $valArr) {
    foreach($valArr as $keyOuter => $valOuter){
        if($keyOuter == "categories"){
            $i=0;
            foreach($valOuter as $keyInner => $valInner){
                if ($valInner == Other) {
                echo '<tr>';
                if ($i < 4) {
                {
                    echo"<td>$keyDec</td>"; 
                    $i+=1;
                }
            }
            echo '</tr>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
echo"</table>";
```

If i use only one foreach the results is exactly what i want, tried with the following code:

```
$i=0;
echo"<table>";
foreach($jsonData['pricing'] as $keyDec => $valArr) {
if($i %4 == 0)
  {
     echo"<tr> <td> $keyDec</td>";  
  }
  else
  {
    echo"<td> $keyDec </td>";  
  }
  $i++;
}
echo"</tr>";
echo"</table>";
```

And results is not like i want, i'm benginer in php, please help me with some optimized php code to make this.

Thank you!

I found the solution:

```
$i=0;
echo '<div class="m-2"><strong>Populare</strong></div>
<table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">';
foreach($jsonData['pricing'] as $keyDec => $valArr) {
    if($valArr[categories][0] == 'Popular') {
      if ($i %4 == 0) {
         echo '<tr><td>.'.$keyDec.''.$valArr[register][1].' '.$jsonData['currency']['suffix'].'</td>';  
      }
      else if ($valArr[categories][0] == 'Popular')
      {
        echo '<td>.'.$keyDec.''.$valArr[register][1].' '.$jsonData['currency']['suffix'].'</td>';  
      }
      $i++;
    }
}
echo '</tr>';
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: You only close the last row of the table because you placed `</tr>` outside of your loop. You need to use a condition for closing the row, similar to what you did for opening the row.

Comment: Also, this: `if ($valInner == Other)` will give you a warning (use of undefined constant) at the moment ("Other" is not quoted). In the future it will be an error.